# jQuery ajax post on every button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Hey I was trying to submit a form with ajax, but the code I wrote submits it on pretty much every button you press on that page. I need to limit it to only a specific button with specific ID when I changed it to be `("#formId").submit` it doesn't work here is the code

```
<form id="formId" method="post">
  <table>
    some table content
  </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(":submit").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this.form);
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: form.serialize() + "&" + this.name + "=" + this.value,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("good stuff");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Keep in mind that code is being generated by while loop (when selecting stuff from database) and I put the JS code at the bottom after the loop.

Comment: If you want to limit it to a specific button with a specific id, then just change the selector to match that button. Although note that `$(this.form)` will need to be changed too.

Comment: When I changed the selector it doesn't work it just reload the page and nothing happens (regular reload not ajax's)

Comment: @Crepitus: Then show that attempt.  How you'd target a specific element is by targeting that specific element.  If you want to know why your code isn't working, show that code and explain that problem.

Comment: I already did it's simple echo from a loop that prints out that form and js code at the end and it works perfect the only problem that the js code being executed on pretty much every button click.

Comment: @Crepitus: Well, if all we can see if the code shown in the question, then you don't even *have* any buttons.  Show code which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: pastebin.com/z9bE3dfy

Comment: @Crepitus: Ok, that code has multiple buttons.  Which specific one do you want to target?  How can that button be distinguished from the other buttons?  Does it have some attribute value which is unique from the others?  Can it be uniquely identified by its position in the HTML?  In the original question you state: *"I need to limit it to only a specific button with specific ID"* - But in your code your buttons *do not have* "specific IDs".  Maybe give an ID to one of them and use that?

Answer (score 1):

Assign your event to the actual form and change the event to `submit` instead of `click`:

```
 jQuery("#formId").on("submit", function (e) {...}
```

Comment: When I changed the selector it doesn't work it just reload the page and nothing happens (regular reload not ajax's)

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I tried 
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#formId").on("submit",function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $("#formId");
       jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "test.php",
           data: form.serialize() + "&" + this.name + "=" + this.value,
           success: function(data)
           {
          alert("good stuff");
           }
         });
      });
     });
    </script>

and also "click" instead of submit and still doesn't work

Comment: What response are you getting back from the ajax request and why are you trying to append stuff to your form's serialized data?

Comment: The response is json array. some strings stored in array and being returned by json. that's why i need to append the response in a div or something i just try with alert for the beginning

Comment: jQuery(":submit").on("click",function (e) { 
this works perfect, but as I said before the only problem with that it is being executed on pretty much every button on the page and when I changed it to be #someId :submit. it just refresh the page and nothing happens.

Comment: Well, with my solution I also noticed for your `data` value in your ajax request change it to `$(this).serialize()`. Not sure if that will be the fix but something to note since `this` is now the form.

Comment: Still doesn't work, if you want to take a look at my html code  
pastebin.com/z9bE3dfy

Answer (score 0):

Give every button a different ID and try the code below, or at least implement something like the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "path_to_script.php",
            data: $("#form_id").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Congratulations this works");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$("#formId :submit").on("click",function(){
    // your ajax code is here...
})
```

Comment: The `click` event on a `form` element will catch all child clicks, not just those on the buttons. I doubt this would be the intended behaviour - or even a workable solution

Comment: Does not work I tried also "submit"

Comment: @Crepitus sorry for my mistake I update my answer please try it now.

Comment: This looked like it would work, but it did not. I also tried bringing back the old way I used which was .click and still. For some reason it ignores the form ID.

Comment: @Crepitus can you please show me your HTML code??

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z9bE3dfy

Comment: Please explain why your code would solve the asker's problem.